# Closure after function definition

Tags: python, closures

Is it possible to define a closure for a function which is already defined?
For example I'd like to have a "raw" function and a function which already has some predefined values set by a surrounding closure.
Here is some code showing what I can do with a closure to add predefined variables to a function definition:

```
def outer(a, b, c):
    def fun(d):
        print(a + b + c - d)
    return fun

foo = outer(4, 5, 6)
foo(10)
```

Now I want to have a definition of `fun` outside of a wrapping closure function, to be able to call `fun` either with variables from a closure or by passing variables directly. I know that I need to redefine a function to make it usable in a closure, thus I tried using `lambda` for it:

```
def fun(a, b, c, d):  # raw function
    print(a + b + c - d)

def clsr(func):  # make a "closure" decorator
    def wrap(*args):
        return lambda *args: func(*args)
    return wrap

foo = clsr(fun)(5, 6, 7)  # make a closure with values already defined
foo(10)  # raises TypeError: fun() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
fun(5, 6, 7, 10)  # prints 8
```

What I also tried is using `wraps` from `functools`, but I was not able to make it work.

But is this even possible? And if yes: Is there any module which already implements decorators for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define the wrap on the fly:

```
def fun(a, b, c, d):  # raw function
    print(a + b + c - d)

def closed(d): fun(5,6,7,d)

closed(10)
```

You can use this with `lambda`, but @juanpa points out you should not if there is no reason to. The above code will result in 8. This method by the way is not Python specific, most languages would support this.

**But if** you need a closure in a sense that it relies on the wrapper variables, than no, and there is good reason not to. This will create essentially a non-working function, that relies on wrapping. In this case using a class maybe better:

```
class fun:
    def __init__(self,*args): #Can use specific things, not just *args.
        self.args = args #Or meaningful names
    def __call__(self,a, b, c, d): # raw function
        print(a + b + c - d,self.args)

def closed(d): 
    fun("some",3,"more",['args'])(5,6,7,d)

closed(10)
```

or using `*args/**kwargs` directly and passing extra variables through that. Otherwise I am not familiar with a "inner function" construct that only works after wrapping.

Comment: Yes, but please don't use `lambda` here. Just use a full function definition. The **only** advantage of `lambda` is that it can be anonymous, if you *name your anonymous function it defeats the purpose of being anonymous*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I cannot say no to such a polite request.

Comment: It also happens to be proscribed by PEP8... :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Polite, Elegant, Programmers?

Comment: Ohhh nooooo. Is it really that easy? Wow. I've been trying around for 2 hours. :D At least I got the part with the redefinition right... Thanks alot kabanus! :)

Comment: I know asking follow-up questions is not good and you'll definetely keep your upvote and marked answer, but since you just answered this perhaps you can also help me with this on the fly. Otherwise I'll post this as a question on monday. Is it also possible to define an array inside the closure which can be mutated by the enclosed function? For example instead of argument `b`, define `b = np.ones(5)` and on each call of the enclosed `fun` calculate `b += b`, while still only having to call the enclosed fun with `closed(10)`?

Comment: @Scotty1- the arguments in the closure passed to the inner function can be whatever you want. If the inner function knows how to handle them, then it will work. Your example, for instance, will work for arguments which are numbers, `numpy` arrays (mixed as well), strings, sets - anything that supports `+` or `-`. The operators do not care!

Comment: Not strings, they do not support `-`, oops.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to save the state of the array `b` between consecutive calls to `closed(10)`, quite much like in a generator. I'll ask a followup question next week. :) Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I just realized that your answer is not a *closure* by the definition that I know, which is that the enclosed function *definition* is nested inside the enclosing function definition and thus the enclosed function is having access to the variables of the enclosing function's scope. This has the major advantage, that variables defined in the enclosing scope are accessible from within the enclosed function. I need it for jit-compiling computing heave functions with numba while reducing typing checks, thus *this kind of closure* is very important to me.

Comment: @Scotty1- Indeed, your example did not require it, and it does not make sense. The function will not work if it is not wrapped. I do not know a language that allows such a construct. Perhaps if you posted a specific example in another question? It really sounds like you want a callable class.

Comment: I'll add my last comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer. I'm already using classes, but the specific function I want to have a closure for, was outsourced and jitted with numba for performance reasons. Thus defining it in a class would bring me back to where I came from. :) But with the functionality of jitclasses, this might still be a good idea.